# What is the best way to handle onchange event on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some textboxes and some textareas inside a div. I have to identify that some values has been changes inside these text boxes or not.

Comment: `$('div').change(function (event) { ... });`

Comment: There is no change event for DIV elements.

Comment: @undefined Maybe he means change of contents.

Comment: @undefined Ha! The point of the question is *slightly* different now.

Comment: @VisioN Yes, _slightly_ :).

Answer (score 3):

if you want to detect for all form elements use:

```
$("div *").change(function(){
  // Whatever
});
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

There is **no change event for div**. If you are trying to figure out the change in html with that div then you can **pool** the html of that div after interval to check if it is changed. You can use `setInterval` to repeadly check the html for it.

Comment: Not sure its a great idea to set a pool for this kind of request, see @Michael Antonius's answer